# what is the way to list one .apk with multiple names on playstore?

Tags: android

From branding perspective I would like to create multiple listings on playstore/ios for my apk (without creating multiple copies of the apk).

How to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the listings are based on the ApplicationId defined during compilation. There arise multiple issues, when doing so:

1. Multiple Apps which are basically the same will confuse the users because they can't distinguish between both. Assume you have two Google Mail apps, which of them would you install? What's the difference?
2. Multiple APKs without any difference will detected as spam and probably removed by Google. Furthermore, if you spam the Store to often your account will be blocked.
3. For your own sake, multiple app listings are hard to maintain, because you probably have to synchronize the store entries in some way.

However, there is a use case, where multiple listings is valuable: you address different markets. For instance you have an app for North America and a different one for Europe. Both apps are basically the same, but they provide different products or address different legal regulations.

In this case, you [create different flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) of your app:

```
productFlavors {
    europe {
        applicationIdSuffix ".europe"
    }
    us {
        applicationIdSuffix ".europe"
    }
}
```